# Swift | Передача cookies в Webview

Tags: ios, swift, webview

всем

У меня есть метод авторизации:

```
static func signIn(body: [String: Any], completion201: @escaping () -> (), completion403: @escaping () -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: Constants.baseUrl + "/auth/login/") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
    request.httpBody = httpBody
    request.method = .post
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    AF.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            if statusCode == 201 {
                completion201()
            } else if statusCode == 403 {
                completion403()
            }
            print(value)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

И есть web-view, в которой открывается страница:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let url = URL(string: Constants.baseUrl)
      let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
      webView.load(request)
  }
```

}

Как я могу в этот web-view передать куки, которые приходят мне после успешной авторизации с помощью моего метода выше? И вообще возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: webview это тот же браузер, только голый. Хотел бы уточнить почему вы на авторизируете в webView, тогда куки сами встанут, а как вариант можете создать при помощи JS все в том же webView. Подсказка: webView может отрисовывать как удаленную ссылку, так и локальный файл или даже просто строку HTML+JS

Comment: Пока нужно самое простое решение, но с нативной регистрацией и авторизацией

Comment: Тогда вам сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716898/set-a-cookie-to-a-webview-in-android . А так первый раз слышу про нативную регистрацию и авторизацию =)